# How can I create a circle fill effect similar to a halftone in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, halftone

I am sort of new to graphic design and need some help on how to recreate this "screen" or "mesh" looking effect for a T-shirt.  I have tried setting this area to gray, using color halftone, and setting the transparency to multiply and it comes close, but the dots seem a little too spread apart and pixelated on Ai.  After trying several things, I am not sure what else to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thank you,

David
[image: T-shirt pattern - Full]

[image: T-shirt pattern - Close-up]

Answer (score 2):

Simply draw a circle with a black fill and a white stroke, then drag that to the **Swatch Panel** to create a pattern swatch. (A)

If you don't want the white stroke.... draw a no-fill, no-stroke rectangle first. Then draw a black circle in the center of that rectangle. Then drag the rectangle and circle to the **Swatch Panel** to create a pattern swatch. (B)

[image]

You cna also simply choose to load the **Basic Dots** pattern file which ships with Illustrator.....

[image]

Comment: Scott, A Big "THANK YOU" for your time and help!

Comment: Hey @DavidLopez - Welcome to GD! If Scott's answer worked for you, feel free to upvote it, and mark it as the accepted answer. This helps ensure the best answers are presented to other users that might visit this page with a similar problem in the future.